# How to get an "username" for "cifs" mounts from ansible_facts?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts, json-query

I need to get cifs mounts credentials, I think getting username from ansible_facts, and after get a password from '/etc/fstab'

But "ansible_facts" => "mounted_devices" => "options"
gaves me not just a credential:

```
"rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=cifsadmin,domain=WORKGROUP,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=127.0.0.1,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1"
```

How can I get just a username from this string?

```
set_fact:
    mounted_devices: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query('[].options') }}"
    register: mounted_devices
```

If I could get cifs credentials I will be able to relocate them to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `regex_search` filter to find and return a substring based on a matched pattern. To return the username from your example string:

```
- set_fact:
    username: "{{ options_string | regex_search('username=([^,]+)', '\\1') | first }}"
```

However, in your question you are assuming that `mounted_devices` is a string, which it isn't - it is an array of strings. I am making some assumptions here, but I think you will need something like this:

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mounted_devices: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?fstype=='cifs'].options"

    - set_fact:
        username: "{{ mounted_devices[0] | regex_search('username=([^,]+)', '\\1') | first }}"

    - debug: var=username
```

That will return the username from the first cifs mount. If there are more than one, with different usernames, you will need additional logic in your playbook.